# Как сделать распознавание tesseract более точным

Tags: python, распознавание-символов, tesseract

Пробовал все psm, oem - система отказывается распознать самый простенький текст

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(col2,config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]